# Overwriting the same row with ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have the following ajax and php files to enter data to my current mytable table.  The below codes work together perfectly fine as they are.

Ajax file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function insertData() {
    var stata=$("#stata").val();
    var statb=$("#statb").val();
    var statc=$("#statc").val();


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update.php",
            data: {stata:stata,statb:statb,statc:statc},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
             $("#message").html(data);
            $("p").addClass("alert alert-success");
            },
            error: function(err) {
            alert(err);
            }
        });

}

</script>
```

update.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$stata=$_POST['stata'];
$statb=$_POST['statb'];
$statc=$_POST['statc'];

$stmt = $DBcon->prepare("REPLACE INTO mytable (stata,statb,statc) VALUES(:stata, :statb,:statc)");

$stmt->bindparam(':stata', $stata);
$stmt->bindparam(':statb', $statb);
$stmt->bindparam(':statc', $statc);
if($stmt->execute())
{
  $res="Data Inserted Successfully:";
  echo json_encode($res);
}
else {
  $error="Not Inserted,Some Problem occur.";
  echo json_encode($error);
}

?>
```

What I'd like to do is to overwrite the same row (update or replace)in the table ( like where id=1) every time I enter the data.

But when I add `"Where id=1"` to the sql query, I get [object Object] error on the screen. I couldn't make it work any way I tried. How can I overcome this problem? thanks.

Comment: Well first you'll need to know what the actual error is.  `alert()` is useless with anything other than simple values, use `console.log()` instead and check the browser's console.  Additionally, if the database is producing an error, don't ignore that error and return a generic message, but get actual information about the error: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php  Also, if the error occurs when you add a `WHERE` clause, then why doesn't your code have a `WHERE` clause?  Are you not using the code which produces the error?  Does *this code* produce an error?

Comment: The above code doesn't produce error. it works without errors as it is. It produces the error when I include where id=1 to the query.

Comment: Ok, so let's focus on the code which *doesn't* work instead of the code which *does* work.  Show the code which produces the error, and get the error message from the database.  This shouldn't be a guessing game.  Have you also checked the syntax for `REPLACE` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html) and `UPDATE` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)?

Comment: thanks, David. I got a solution. I will check the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update the row (not replace it), use `UPDATE` instead of `REPLACE`.

```
UPDATE mytable SET stata = :stata, statb = :statb, statc = :statc WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the datatype. 
JSON requests usually return JSON objects and not strings.
`Console.log(data)` then find out the string value of the error then use it the correct key.
Also if an error occurs on your server code it will return a JSON object instead of just a string so you have to traverse the object till you get the string you want to output in the
`$("#message")`